# why my onclick event triggers automatically

Tags: javascript, html

'Hello World' is initially displayed when page is loaded. I want it displayed only after the button is clicked. I know I can do this by adding inline event listener to button. Can I code all these just in script?

```
        <button id="demo1">Click Me</button>

        <p id="demo"></p> 

        <script> document.getElementById('demo1').onclick = myFunction(); 
            function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World"; } 
        </script>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're immediately invoking myFunction, and then assigning the return value (which is undefined) to onclick

`document.getElementById('demo1').onclick = myFunction();`

should be

`document.getElementById('demo1').onclick = myFunction;`

Comment: If you're ever using this style of Event Listening and you need to pass, multiple arguments to your function then you should know `Element.onclick = function(evenObjectIsPassedHere){ myFunction.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3); }` is how you do that. Of course, you can pass the Event Object to your inner Function as well. I'm showing to use `call` so you can bind the `this` context to your Element, then `myFunction` could have things like `this.style.color = 'green';` in it. You could also `call()` that in the context of your output Element.